# I want to upload multiple images at a time using Laravel 5.4 and php. Please guide me step wise.

Tags: php, laravel

I am building an android app for adding product details to the database. The need of the hour is that I have to send more than 1 image for the description of the product. I want assistance in writing a Post API using Laravel 5.4 framework which could accept the multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

## For Multiple Images

Use HTML like as follow on blade

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="eventimages[]" >
```

## Inside Your controller use as follows

```
if($request->hasFile('eventimages'))
{
   foreach($request->file('eventimages') as $image) {
       $destinationPath = storage_path('content_images/');
       $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
       $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
       $image = new ImageModel;
       $image->create_by       = '1';
       $image->image_name     = $filename;
       $result = $image->save(); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: I am a beginner in Laravel and as far as I know there is no blade file in my C Panel. And I want to store the images in database using multipart. Please suggest me the code